# show multiple image in matplotlib from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an array with the shape (1, 64, 224, 224). 64 Single channel images of size 224*224. When I do this:

```
plt.imshow(output_image[0,1,:,:], interpolation='nearest')
```

The image is displayed properly.

But when I do:

```
for i in range(64):
    plt.imshow(output_image[0,i,:,:], interpolation='nearest')
```

I see only 1 image as result even though there are 64 images.

How can I get a line of 64 images? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use the `extent` kwarg to move them from overlapping.

Comment: @tacaswell Thanks! I am new to Python , an example of how I might do this will be nice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a new subplot for each image:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50, 50))  # width, height in inches

for i in range(64):
    sub = fig.add_subplot(64, 1, i + 1)
    sub.imshow(output_image[0,i,:,:], interpolation='nearest')
```

This will put all 64 images in one column. Change to:

```
sub = fig.add_subplot(8, 8, i + 1)
```

for eight columns and eight rows.

Comment: This works ! but the images are really small . The original image is 224*224 quite big. How do i increase the image size in the plot ?

Comment: You can specify a figure size. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

this function creates subplot for each image:
the `img` has shape of `(n,height,width,channel)`

```
import numpy as np
def picshow(img):
    num = len(img)
    ax = np.ceil(np.sqrt(num)) 
    ay = np.rint(np.sqrt(num)) 
    fig =plt.figure()
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        sub = fig.add_subplot(ax,ay,i)
        sub.set_title("titre",i)
        sub.axis('off')
        sub.imshow(data[i-1])
    plt.show()
```